# Email spoofing possibility?

Tags: mail-server, spf, dkim, spoofing, network-security

I would like to know if it is possible to spoof an email address like in the following scenario. If so, what other measures could I adopt in order to prevent the spoofing?

[image]

Do I need to make use of SPF, DKIM, etc? If so, then how?

Comment: Not really a programming question, this might fit ServerFault - [sf] . Google DKIM and SPF to see how to set them up.  They authenticate a mail server, but if the bandit has your user name and password they can pretend to be you.

Answer (score 1):

Only if your email server was an open relay, then the bandit user can send mail through your server.

Now keep in mind any bandit user can send email as "bill@mybusiness.com", but it won't come from your email servers IP address.

Even with SPF - all that will do is cause a hard failure, if your SPF ended with "-all". It's up to the end user email server to determine what to do with the hard SPF failure.

Setting [DMARC Reject Policy](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarc/) is a much better way to go and most major ESP providers will reject those emails to reduce spoofing.